# "Wait for field changes in current item" in visual studio workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, development, visual-studio

I'm developing sequential workflow for document library in visual studio. I want to wait for field changes in current item. I am seeking for the action Just similar to "**Wait For Field Change in Current Items**" action in sharepoint designer workflow.

[MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflowactions.waitforactivity.aspx), [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c9493ebb-9907-48be-aa0a-8e0689d67c4d/pause-until-field-change-in-current-item?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) says, "WaitForActivity" class pause the workflow until the value of the specified list field has the specified relationship to the specified value. But there is no sample code on how to implement this class.

Can anyone knows ? OR any alternative solution ? Thank you.